# Is it possible to see app downloads by country?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it possible to see app downloads by country?

I checked

Sales and Trends
View and download your sales and trends information.

part but it only seems to show the region. Is it possible to somehow learn which countries downloaded my application?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app sales and not about programming.

Comment: It is not about app sales, it is about app statistics and part of ios development experience in general. If you know which SE site to post, the post can be moved there.

Comment: is there a way to move post without use of mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really great tool I've been using is AppViz.  It gives you all sorts of stats

Comment: AppViz went out of business and abandoned all of their users.